# how to go back to previous page when refresh the screen in pageview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-pageview

I want to keep the current page, when i refersh the screen or navigating back in page view
here is the code , actually i want display  the particular index screen programmatically with out clicking the button. Some times iam getting controller.hasClients getting empty. If page view has 3 screens , if iam on 2ndscreen  when i refresh the second screen should display second screen, instead it always display 1st screen . Iam using  page controller to display , but  not able to instantiate page controller becacuse i want to access from top widgets of page view. Please help

```
      Container(
          // width: 370,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.685,
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            _pages(),

            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                          (i == currentPage
                              ? circleBar(true)
                              : circleBar(false))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ]),
        ),

           Widget _pages() {
List _pagesList = [
  FirstScreen(
   
  ),
  SecondScreen(
   
  ),
  ThirdScreen(
      ),
];


return PageView.builder(
  controller: _pageController,
  itemCount: _pagesList.length,
 // restorationId: currentPage.toString(),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
   // _pageController=PageController(initialPage: currentPage);
    return _pagesList[index];
  },
  onPageChanged: (int page) {
    setState(() {
      currentPage = page;
      selected = analyticsList[currentPage].anlyticName;
      isIndexChanged = true;
      page;
    });
  },
);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first saving the current page and  instantiating page controller in pages() it worked for me

i just instantiated the page controller in pages() in my code as if declare on the top it is not  getting read every  refresh so i declared where the pageview get build .

```
Widget _pages() {

   _pageController= PageController(initialPage: currentPage, keepPage: true);
    List _pagesList = [
      FirstScreen(
        
      ),
     SecondScreen(
       
      ),
      ThirdScreen(
          ),
    ];


    return PageView.builder(
      controller: _pageController,
      itemCount: _pagesList.length,
     // restorationId: currentPage.toString(),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

        return _pagesList[index];
      },
      onPageChanged: (int page) {
        setState(() {
          currentPage = page;
          selected = analyticsList[currentPage].anlyticName;
          isIndexChanged = true;

          page;
        });
      },
    );



  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a named route, you can use this code.

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/screen2').then((_) {
  // This block runs when you have returned back from screen 2.
  setState(() {
    // code here to refresh data
  });
});
```

Comment: if page view has 3 screens , if iam on 2ndscreen  when i refresh the second screen should display second screen, instead it always display 1st screen, by the way iam using page controller